# MPMusicPlayerController Volume Fade

Tags: ios, ipod, volume

I have:

```
 MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
```

When using the app, I need to bring down the music to sound an alarm and when it goes away, I want to bring it up to previous volume. musicVolume here is a double which stores the volume level before fading:

```
musicVolume = musicPlayer.volume;
if (musicPlayer.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying)
    [self fadeMusicOut];
```

This fade the music out well.

To fade it back in:

```
    - (void) fadeMusicIn
    {
            [musicPlayer play];
            musicPlayer.volume += 0.05;
            if (musicPlayer.volume < musicVolume)
                [self performSelector: @selector(fadeMusicIn) 
                           withObject: nil 
                           afterDelay: 0.1 ];
            else 
            {

            }
    }
```

This fades music back in well, however, it always bring up the volume LESS THAN what was set before.

Howcan I acheive this to get back to original volume?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You are saying `if (musicPlayer.volume < musicVolume)` Which is basically stopping the `performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:` method from being called, or any method called in that if statement, once the `musicPlayer.volume` is equal or bigger to the `musicVolume`. But you want it to be equal. So try:

```
- (void) fadeMusicIn
{
    ...
        if (musicPlayer.volume == musicVolume)
            [self performSelector: @selector(fadeMusicIn) 
                       withObject: nil 
                       afterDelay: 0.1 ];
    ...
}
```

This way the if statement stops if `musicPlayer.volume` is smaller OR equal, so once its equal, it stops

Update, try == instead

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I did try this, which makes the difference a little less.  However, problem still exists.  Lets say you start with Volume 0.8.  You fade it down to 0.0 and fade back in to 0.8.  At this point, I got a NSLog out of both musicPlayer.Volume and musicVolume, they both reads the same.  However, actual music volume coming out the headphones are waaaaay less.